# Подводные камни передачи объект класса asio::io_context в динамическую библиотеку

Tags: c++, dll, asio, boost.asio

Есть приложение с плагинами.

Приложение создает `asio::io_context` и передает его в плагины при их инициализации.

В приложении:

```
asio::io_context ctx; // Уничтожается только при выходе из приложения

//...

auto plugins = LoadPlugins(); // Load DLL-s

for(auto p: plugins)
{
   p->Init(&ctx); // Send CTX object from APP into DLL
}
```

Где то в плагине

```
ctx->SomeMethod(...); // use object from APP in DLL
```

При этом `ctx->SomeMethod` может быть шаблонным.

UPD: вопрос можно обобщить на передачу любых сложных объектов(`std::string`, например) через границу `application <-> dll`

Какие подводные камни есть в подобном подходе?

Comment: Вы бы поподробнее про схему взаимодействия приложения с плагинами (жизненный цикл плагина, можно назвать это так) написали

Answer (score -2):

### Тема

*В подобном подходе есть несколько потенциальных подводных камней:*

---

### Подводные камни

**1.** Взаимодействие с памятью: При передаче объекта `asio::io_context` из основного приложения в плагины, необходимо быть осторожным с управлением памятью. Если плагин сохраняет указатель на объект `asio::io_context` и продолжает использовать его после того, как основное приложение завершит свою работу и освободит память, может возникнуть ошибка доступа к памяти.

**2.** Взаимодействие с потоками: `asio::io_context` является многопоточным объектом, и его использование в нескольких потоках может потребовать синхронизации доступа к нему. Если плагины используют `asio::io_context` в разных потоках, необходимо убедиться, что доступ к нему синхронизирован правильным образом.

**3.** Жизненный цикл объекта `asio::io_context`: Если основное приложение завершает свою работу раньше, чем плагины, могут возникнуть проблемы с использованием объекта `asio::io_context` в плагинах. Плагины должны быть осторожны и проверять, что объект `asio::io_context` все еще действителен перед его использованием.

**4.** Версионирование и совместимость: Если основное приложение и плагины разрабатываются и собираются независимо друг от друга, необходимо обеспечить совместимость версий. Изменения в `asio::io_context` или его зависимостях могут привести к несовместимости между приложением и плагинами.

**5.** Безопасность: Передача объекта `asio::io_context` из основного приложения в плагины может представлять потенциальную уязвимость безопасности. Плагины, получающие доступ к объекту `asio::io_context`, могут иметь возможность влиять на работу основного приложения или злоупотреблять его возможностями.

---

### Итог

В целом, передача объекта `asio::io_context` из основного приложения в плагины может быть полезным и эффективным подходом, но требует осторожности и правильного управления памятью, потоками и безопасностью.

Comment: Вы пишете в (1) и (3) про возможные проблемы с памятью после завершения основного приложения.   А как  вы вообще представляете себе логику работы плагина после завершения основного приложения?

Comment: @avp Мало смысла критиковать копипасту из чатгтп.

Comment: @user7860670, я подозревал что-то подобное, вот и решил немного проверить автора. Раз пока молчит, значит сам плохо понимает тему